# Maps API key doesn't work

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm attempting to bring up sample maps using my just-acquired browser API key. Naturally, it doesn't work. I'm getting the error message:
"Google has disabled the use of the Maps API for this app. The provided key is not a valid API key or it is not authorized for the Google Maps API v3 on this site."

The API key I'm using is definitely a browser key, not a server key, copied straight from the Google API site. And I'm using the Chrome browser. So the big question is: why is the key "not authorized for Google Maps API on this site." Maybe there's something weird about v3, and I should be using v2 or something. (I'm new to the arcane world of Google API keys.)

Here's the API key source info: 
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBEhHjDXpu7OFJsNd00YHzYR1Jcsbj-eHY&sensor=false">

Hopefully, I'm overlooking something obvious, but if so, I'd appreciate knowing what it is!

Appreciate any help. Thanks, Jack K

Comment: What referrers are valid for that key?  Are they correct for the page you have your map on?

Comment: Do you have the Google Maps Javascript API v3 turned on in the API console?

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue two weeks ago. It seems Google does now only requires a token if you're planning to use it for business purposes (with increase daily quotas). 
If you did not let your credit cards details in the api console the token is not considered as a business one. It's then considered as invalid.

Removing the token (including the parameter name) from the request should resolve you issue :)

Comment: Oh my god. Been looking for hours for a solution. Thank you!

Comment: @user3266977 , I guess it's the right solution, could you please accept the answer ? Thanks !